# AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB) Body Based Routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, url-routing, aws-application-load-balancer

In AWS, I would like to process messages posted to an http endpoint by inspecting an identifying field within each message and then routing them to an AWS ALB with (for example) a custom host header determined from that identifying field so that an ALB rule can then forward to a specific target group that handles the type of message that was identified.

I was thinking I could have an initial ALB receive the messages and then use a lambda function as the target which could do the message inspection, check the identifying field and then route the message onto the ALB with the host header rules based on the content of that field.

Is this a reasonable way to do body-based routing? Or is there a better way?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use API gateway to take the body of the message and add host headers based on attributes in the data. Your logic can't get particularly complex, but simple mapping is very doable. From there you can have the API Gateway route to your ALB with routing based on the headers.

Comment: I didn't know API Gateway could do that, it might not help me in this situation but I am sure I will make use of that in the future! :) Basically, I think this situation may be too complex as the message is not always JSON and also the source identifying field might have around 1000 values that will map to say a total of 5 destinations. It will prob be a table lookup with a small bit of logic. i am going to read the api gateway docs though to get more detail on its capabilities.

Comment: API-Gateway is really cool. But every API-Call will be charged. This could become a bold pricetag at the end of a month.